# Can't remove the background of google chart

Tags: google-visualization

I have used google charts for a web app. I want to **remove its white background**. I tried changing the **background color to transparent**, but it **isn't working**.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
google.charts.load("current", {packages:["corechart"]});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ["Element", "Density", { role: "style" } ],
    ["LIC", 8.94, "#BCFFFF"],
    ["STAR", 10.49, "#FFC9C9"],
    ["UNIVERSAL", 19.30, "#F9FFD3"],
    ["APPOLLO", 21.45, "#C2FFBD"]
  ]);

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setColumns([0, 1,
                   { calc: "stringify",
                     sourceColumn: 0,
                     type: "string",
                     role: "annotation" },
                   2]);

  var options = {
    title: "CUSTOMERS",
    bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
    
    legend: { position: "none" },
  };
  var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById("barchart_values"));
  chart.draw(view, options);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var options = {
title: "CUSTOMERS",
bar: {groupWidth: "70%"},
backgroundColor: 'transparent',
legend: { position: "none" },
```

It works now, don't know why it didn't work before.